# Converted Int returns NaN

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
var fifty = prompt("Enter amount ");
var twenty;
alert(twenty=parseInt(fifty/50) + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
alert(parseInt(twenty/20) + " x " + "20 dollar bill");
```

What I'm trying to count is dollar bills.
For example when I enter "120" it should return 2x 50 bills and 1x 20 dollar bill, I understand that returned value is String type so I'm converting them number, but on 20 dollar bills it returns "Nan x 20 dollar bils" I'm  having trouble understanding why

Comment: your `twenty` contains a string `[number] + " x " +   "50 dollar bill"`

Comment: Yes but shouldn't parseInt still convert that into a number? as far as I understand when converting a String to number everything right of actual number is disregarded

Comment: @JhonDhoe That's what `parseInt` do. But as browser evaluate `twenty/20` first, and it assume you tries to divide a `string` by 20. It won't call parseInt, it use Nubmer(twenty) to convert it to a number, and it becomes `NaN`. Ref: [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 1):

I've shuffled around your variable names to make it a bit clearer.

```
// I'll use the example of 120 to demonstrate

// The total amount, e.g. 120
var amount = prompt("Enter amount ");

// First, convert the inputted string into an int
var amountAsInt = parseInt(amount, 10);

// Then, divide by 50 (which equals 2.4), and then use 
// Math.floor() to "chop off" the decimal part
var numberOfFifties = Math.floor(amountAsInt/50);
// Leaving us with numberOfFifties = 2

// We can now use 'modulus' to give the amount left.
// If you haven't come across modulus before, it gives
// the remainder after dividing by the given number (here: 50)
var amountLeft = amount % 50;

// Do the same with the amount left to find the number of 20s
var numberOfTwenties = Math.floor(amountLeft / 20);

if(numberOfFifties > 0){alert(numberOfFifties + " x " + "50 dollar bill(s)");}
if(numberOfTwenties > 0){alert(numberOfTwenties + " x " + "20 dollar bill(s)");}
```

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7p57e3u1/3/

**Reason for the NaN**

You can see the reason why you were getting an NaN by looking at this JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pto52oe5/

You are setting twenty to be equal to the whole string, hence it is "Not a Number" (NaN).

```
alert(twenty=parseInt(fifty/50) + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
```

Here, you appear to be assuming that

```
twenty=parseInt(fifty/50)
```

will be treated as a separate "part", but in actual fact, it uses the whole expression, setting `twenty` to be the whole string that is output in the alert():

```
twenty = parseInt(fifty / 50) + " x " + "50 dollar bill"
```

i.e. (for the example above)

```
twenty = "2 x 50 dollar bill"
```

A useful technique for debugging (and creating more understandable and therefore maintainable code) is to split things down into very simple steps, as I have in the example code above.  This (arguably) is broken down too far, but use that as a first technique to break down a problem like this.

Comment: Can you please tell me why do we multiply NumOf50 by 50

Comment: You dont need 2 `parseInt`'s here - once you've parsed the input to an int you dont need to do it again when dividing by 50!

Comment: @JhonDhoe I've updated the code so that it's more clear what's going on.  Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: @Jamiec My bad - should have used Math.floor() - now updated

Comment: A little advice, `var amountLeft = amountAsInt % 50;` should be enough.

Comment: D'oh, thanks @fuyushimoya - didn't think of that for some reason...  updated the answer above.

Comment: I've just altered this slightly to specify the radix, as this is best practice (to prevent octal being assumed by older implementations of ECMAScript): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @JhonDhoe if you like my answer, please could you accept it (green tick)?  I'm trying to improve my reputation score :)

Answer (score 1):

Please stop using `parseInt` for separating integer part of float value, use it only to convert string into integer. When you are using `parseInt` float value is converted into string and than some integer number is parsed back, there can be situation when float number will be converted in string like `5.1234E-6` and `parseInt` will return `5` in this case. Use `Math.floor()` instead.

```
var sum = parseInt(prompt("Enter amount "));
var twenty = Math.floor(sum/50);
alert(twenty + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
alert(Math.floor((sum - (twenty*50))/20) + " x " + "20 dollar bill");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm not trying to fix the algorithm here, but just the input errors and type.

You should first parse `fifty` to an int, then only divide it by `50`, since you want an int even after dividing by `50` you can let the initial `parseInt`.

Also, be aware that parseInt needs a radix (10 here), and it may still return `NaN` if a non parseable value is given.

```
var fifty = parseInt(prompt("Enter amount "), 10);
alert(twenty=parseInt(fifty/50, 10) + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
```

As an alternative, you could use the bitwise or (`|`) which acts almoste like `parseInt(x, 10)` except that when it would have returned `NaN` with `parseInt`, it would return `0` with the bitwise or operator.

Using `|`

```
var fifty = prompt("Enter amount ") | 0;
alert(twenty=((fifty/50)|0) + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
var fifty = prompt("Enter amount ");
var twenty;
twenty=parseInt(fifty/50);
var rem = fifty - (twenty * 50);
alert(twenty + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
alert(parseInt(rem/20) + " x " + "20 dollar bill");
```

Hope it will help !!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your logic.

Maybe something like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/2e7cs06v/

```
var total = prompt("Enter amount ");
var numOf50=parseInt(total/50);
var moneyLeft = total - (numOf50 * 50);
alert(numOf50 + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
alert(parseInt(moneyLeft/20) + " x " + "20 dollar bill");
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why do we multiply NumOf50 by 50?

Comment: because we want to know how much money was left from the total after we reduce the amount of 50s, so in your example it's 120 - (2 * 50) = 20

Answer (score 0):

Because you have parsing more string (+ " x " +   "50 dollar bill") into parseInt() function. So parseInt function not able to pars "dollar bill" text value.

```
var fifty = prompt("Enter amount ");
var twenty = parseInt(fifty/50);

alert( twenty + " x " +   "50 dollar bill");
alert(parseInt(twenty/20) + " x " + "20 dollar bill");
```